# Makefile always builds even when no changes

Tags: makefile, latex, gnu-make, tex

I have the following Makefile for running pdflatex on tex source files:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --warn-undefined-variables

deps := mydoc.tex mydoc.cls

mydoc.pdf: $(deps)

.PHONY: build
build:  $(deps) 
    pdflatex mydoc.tex mydoc.pdf

.PHONY: build
clean:  ## Delete misc
    rm -f mydoc.out mydoc.pdf mydoc.aux mydoc.log
```

When I run `make build` it always runs pdflatex even though `mydoc.tex` has not changed.

My understanding is `make build` should say there is nothing to do if `mydoc.tex` has not changed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you've declared the target `build` to be `.PHONY`.  The entire point of a phony target is that it will always be considered out of date and its recipe will be invoked.  So, of course the recipe is always run.

Even if you remove the `.PHONY` though, the recipe will always be run.  You say make should do nothing is `mydoc.tex` has not changed... well, how can make know that `mydoc.tex` has not changed?  Not changed compared to what?  Make doesn't have its own database that tells it the last time it ran, and what all the timestamps on the files were at some time in the past.  It simply relies on comparing timestamps of files on the filesystem as they exist now.

When you write a rule it tells make, *if any of the prerequisites have a newer modification time than the target, then the target is out of date and the recipe should be run to bring it up to date*.

So if you write a rule `build: mydoc.tex` make will look to see if the prerequisite `mydoc.tex` is newer than the target `build`.  Since there is no file `build` and one is never created, `mydoc.tex` will always be considered newer than a non-existent file, and the recipe will always be run.

You need to be sure that the target of the rule is the file that is updated by the recipe.  Best practice is to ensure that every recipe you write (that updates a file) updates the file contained in the `$@` automatic variable:

```
mydoc.pdf:  $(deps) 
        pdflatex mydoc.tex $@
```

Comment: Ok, I removed .PHONY, but to execute this then, I have to say `make mydoc.pdf,` is that correct?  I've seen people use `make build` as kind of an alias for an action. Are you saying I have to create a file called `build` that depends on `mydoc.pdf` in order to run `make build` in such a way that it only conditionally executes?

Comment: Use a phony target `build` and a `build: mydoc.pdf` dependency without recipe. You'll be able to run `make build` as an alias of `make mydoc.pdf`.

Comment: If you give no target on the make command line (just type `make`) it will build the first target it sees in the makefile.  If you put the target `mydoc.pdf` first, then running `make` with no argument will build that target.  If you give a target on the command line, like `make mydoc.pdf`, then make will build whatever target you gave.  If you want to have a target `build` that will build `mydoc.pdf`, then as Renaud suggests you can create a target `build` that lists `mydoc.pdf` as a prerequisite.  But, the rule with the recipe for building `mydoc.pdf` **MUST** have a target named `mydoc.pdf`.